# SQL find multiple occurence in a filed

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a small problem. with a SQL request

I want to find in my table in a field if there is a double or more occurence or a character.

I explain :

`"Hello World";` // There is 3 l

How can i do like a regex or something else like : `where nom like "%l%l%"` ?

I tried `select nom from distrib where MATCH (nom) AGAINST ('%y%' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` but i don't think it's the good choice.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (col - name of the field, l - character):

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(col) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(col, 'l', ''))
```

Comment: Nice i could make this in where >= 2 and done what i wanted Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain  number of occurrence in this way where `_the_char` mean the char you want find ..

```
SELECT 
   ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(your_field)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( your_field, "_the_char", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("_the_char")        
) AS count
```